# Find all database tables where a common column is set to a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

All database tables have a UserId field of [uniqueidentifier] type.

I need to query the entire database and get the list of tables that have UserId set to a specific value.
Right now I achieved this by using cursor and the results are horrible and are difficult to read. How can I improve this query to retrieve back a clear list with tables and count of record that have UserId set to a specific value, instead of using this:

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(127);
DECLARE @Value VARCHAR(512);
DECLARE @SqlCommand varchar(1000)

--Use cursor to loop through database tables that contain UserId column
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT t.name AS TableName
    FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE c.name = 'UserId';
OPEN db_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @TableName;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

 --Check if the next table has any UserId matching the where clause
 EXEC('SELECT COUNT(UserId) ,  ''' + @TableName + ''' FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE UserId = ''FF13ACCA-022C-4296-AB3D-A35700E35BB3''');


   FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @TableName;
END;
CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made all the difficult part, just put the value in a temp table and select them once you've finished.

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(127);
DECLARE @Value VARCHAR(512);
DECLARE @SqlCommand varchar(1000)

--Creta temp table
CREATE TABLE #Results (Number int, Tablename sysname)
--Use cursor to loop through database tables that contain UserId column
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT t.name AS TableName
    FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE c.name = 'UserId';
OPEN db_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @TableName;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

 --Check if the next table has any UserId matching the where clause
 EXEC('INSERT INTO #Results (Number, ''' + @TableName + ''') SELECT COUNT(UserId) ,  ''' + @TableName + ''' FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE UserId = ''FF13ACCA-022C-4296-AB3D-A35700E35BB3''');

   FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @TableName;
END;
CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;

SELECT * FROM #Results
DROP TABLE #Results
```

I cannot test it but this should be the way

Comment: I had to adjust some syntax in the Insert statement that adds data to the temp table but it worked. Thank you.